# how to add space if length of string is more

Tags: java

I need to set a `string` size only up to 22 if `String` value is more than 22 I need to show 10 empty characters(Empty space) from 23rd letter onwards. How to do this small logic?

```
if (name.length()>22)
        {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            stringBuilder.append(name+"%+23s");
        }
```

Is this logic is correct?

Answer (score 0):

You could use **[setLength](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#setLength(int))**

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
..
..
if (stringBuilder.length () > 22)
{
   stringBuilder.setLength(22);
   stringBuilder.append(" ");// append number of space characters here
}
```

Comment: So I just need to write `stringBuilder.apped(" ");`

Comment: @john that is an example. You need to specify same number of space characters inside append, which I clearly mentioned in comment

Comment: but how does that will append to the name? you are appending length to the StringBuilder reference

Comment: @john This is an example of how you can achieve what you are trying to do. Are you clear with what above code does ? if yes, then you shouldn't have asked above question.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (name.length() > 22) {
    name = name.substring(0,22) + "          " + name.substring(23);
}
```

Comment: `name.substring(22)` will not work, you probably meant `name.substring(0, 23)`

Comment: @gifpif explanation, please?

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.stream.*;
public class StringTester {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String name = "The Adventures of Sherlock Holmes";
        if (name.length() > 22) {
            String result = Stream.iterate(" ", s -> s)
                                   .limit(10)
                                   .collect(Collectors.joining("", name.substring(0, 22), ""));
            System.out.println("<" + result + ">");
            // Prints the name within < and >.
            // NOTE: The delimiters < and > are used to show the 10 spaces
            // after the first 22 characters of name.
            System.out.println(result.length()); // prints: 32 = 22 chars + 10 spaces
            // If required build a StringBuilder object:
            StringBuilder newName = new StringBuilder(result);
        }
    }
}
```